# Can't Install Mongoose via NPM

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm

I am trying to download mongoose into my node.js project via npm.

The command is `npm install mongoose`. However, this leads to the below output, and eventually leads to an error. The only things in the mongoose directory are the dependencies (in the node_modules folder). Any other package will work, but mongoose repeatedly fails. I've tried `npm install -g mongoose` and `sudo npm install mongoose`, but neither of them work either.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

node version 0.10.20

npm version 1.3.11

```
$ npm install mongoose
npm WARN package.json mongo@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sliced/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hooks/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/muri/0.3.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb/1.3.19
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/regexp-clone/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mpath/0.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mpromise/0.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sliced/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hooks/0.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/muri/0.3.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb/1.3.19
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/regexp-clone/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mpath/0.1.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mpromise/0.2.1
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/index.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! command "/Users/khanh/.nvm/v0.10.20/bin/node" "/Users/khanh/.nvm/v0.10.20/bin/npm" "install" "mongoose"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.20
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! path /Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/index.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/index.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /Users/khanh/.nvm/v0.10.20/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks'
npm ERR! error rolling back  mongoose@3.6.20 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks' }
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpath/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! command "/Users/khanh/.nvm/v0.10.20/bin/node" "/Users/khanh/.nvm/v0.10.20/bin/npm" "install" "mongoose"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.20
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! path /Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpath/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/README.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! command "/Users/khanh/.nvm/v0.10.20/bin/node" "/Users/khanh/.nvm/v0.10.20/bin/npm" "install" "mongoose"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.20
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! path /Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/README.md
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Any more info in the mentioned `/Users/khanh/Code/bunnybots/npm-debug.log`? Also, try running `npm cache clean` and try again.

Comment: Cleaning the cache worked. I have all of the files now. Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `npm cache clean`.

After that, install as normal, and the download should proceed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

stop node server if its running, that was the problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Try this:

```
npm install -s mongoose
```

This will install it on your app, in fact on your `package.json`. It will be available as dependencies so you can easily `require` it.

Otherwise try

```
sudo npm install -g mongoose
```

That should also work, from your output above I can see that you haven't tried that.

Answer (score 0):

- Make index.js file in the folder where you have made the empty file of node using the command

  ```js
  npm init
  ```
- Now try to install mongoose using command

  ```js
  npm install mongoose
  ```

If this doesn't work

- delete the folder in which you have made empty node project.
- then again make the same folder and then use the above instruction.

Answer (score 0):

"`npm cache clean --force` ->> `npm i mongoose`" Worked for me.